# Block VPN completely on Android

Tags: vpn

For some reason, I want to block the VPN completely from my smartphone; So I can't run any VPN app, or connect to the VPN manually.

I want the simplest and easiest way to set a security policy that blocks VPN on Android.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible, but you could try to define your own VPN as always-on-VPN. As far as I know Android can only one VPN at a time so with that always active VPN all other VPN connections can not be used.